# Can a non-Briton become Minister of Magic?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

An online quiz told my sister she would be best suited to the profession of Minister of Magic. The only problem I saw with that is that she is not British (she is American). I am not aware of anything in the canon works that enforces this belief, however, I’m simply basing it on the idea that this is a general rule for electing top officials in (Muggle) governments across the world.

Is there any basis for thinking this that anyone might know of?

Comment: Given that it's not really clear on what basis wizards have citizenship (or even if they have citizenship since they're essentially a parasite society within their muggle host countries) and hence whether an American wizard could have a rank in the British Ministry

Comment: My suspicion is that at the very least Irish wizards would be allowed to.

Answer (score 3):

## There’s nothing that states the Minister of Magic *has* to be British.

There’s not much known on the criteria used to choose the Minister of Magic, or if there are any requirements they must fulfill to be eligible other than being a wizard (presumably). They’re usually elected, but the post can also be just given to someone during times of crisis.

> The Ministry of Magic was formally established in 1707 with the appointment of the very first man to hold the title ‘Minister for Magic’, Ulick Gamp.* The Minister for Magic is democratically elected, although there have been times of crisis in which the post has simply been offered to an individual without a public vote (Albus Dumbledore was made such an offer, and turned it down repeatedly).
>
> <sub>* Prior to 1707, the Wizards’ Council was the longest serving (though not the only) body to govern the magical community in Britain. After the imposition of the International Statute of Secrecy in 1692, however, the wizarding community needed a more highly structured, organised and more complex governing structure than they had hitherto used, to support, regulate and communicate with a community in hiding. Only witches and wizards who enjoyed the title of ‘Minister for Magic’ are included in this entry.</sub> 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ministers for Magic (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)*</sup></sub>

It seems like the main requirement (in most cases when someone isn’t just appointed) is that the magical community is willing to elect them. Them being from Britain might help them gain votes since British wizards would relate to them more, but in no way is it ever stated to be required.

> The Muggle Prime Minister has no part in appointing the Minister for Magic, whose election is a matter only for the magical community themselves. All matters relating to the magical community in Britain are managed solely by the Minister for Magic, and he has sole jurisdiction over his Ministry. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Ministers for Magic (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic)*</sup></sub>

However, not much is known about if there are any requirements to become Minister of Magic, there aren’t many details given. It’s possible it is required that they are but was never mentioned.

Comment: Good answer Miss Bella! Maybe cite the source? Of course this is from writing by Rowling about Ministers for Magic but I would imagine many don't recognise it - and you might also considering quoting what the **`*`** notes :)

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks a lot! :) Sorry, I forgot - I normally cite the source and agree it’s important to do so. I’ll fix it up now, thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help - as always! Oh and you're only human. You forgot. Well that's not a crime really given that humans are imperfect! :) Yes even formidable foes like Bellatrix Lestrange...

Comment: @Pryftan You definitely are, I’m so glad you caught that for me! :)

Comment: And... that's how it should be here. Keep up the great work Bella, as always!

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks! :) I have an awful cold right now, so it’s harder than usual to make sense. :P